# change quantity of product in woocommerce mini cart ( cart widget )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a solution to be able to change the quantity of each product in the cart widget in ajax, so that the total price change accordingly. 
Right now, I can only see the quantity of each product but I can't change the quantity. 
I can do that but only in cart page, not in cart widget. I tried to replace the min-cart.php with the cart.php code but the layout is not good.

Any solutions ?

Comment: In what scenario does your scheme make sense?

Comment: Just a client asking to be able to change the quantity directly in the mini cart widget so that users don't have to go to the cart page for the quantity

Comment: @Vincent Did you solve this?